# Query to check the data type of a field value is in numeric (INT64) or other data type

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to big query and trying to learn on my own.
I came across with one point, on how to check the field value of a particular column is matching with INT64 datatype(schema of the column) . the query should return the rows if any value of INT64 column is having other data type.
FYI, I am aware of field_path_columns and information_schema but the ask is to check only the datatype of a value in particular field.

appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to find values which cannot be cast to INT64?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE SAFE_CAST(mycolumn AS INT64) IS NULL
```

Comment: my question is to check whether the expression ISNUMERIC(expression) like SQL.
based on my understanding, isnumeric() function doesn't work in bigquery.

Comment: Then SAFE_CAST should work for your use-case

Comment: i was using  this query and i see this is same as your query 

select mycolymn IS NULL or safe_cast(mycolumn AS int64) is not null  from `my-project`
But my query return true/false in the result.